# passing two parameters in index function using codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, indexing, routes

I want to pass two parameters in index function using codeigniter but its giving me error i don't know why its giving me error.
here is my controller

```
function index($one = null,$two = null)
{
    $data['title'] = "Product Page ";
    $this->load->view('home/header/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('home/css/css');
    $this->load->view('home/navbar/navbar2');
    $this->load->view('products/product');
    $this->load->view('home/footer/footer');
    $this->load->view('home/js/js');
}
```

here is my routes setting

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'product/index/$1';
```

When i set my index function in one parameter its working fine but its not working with two parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this, it will be working

```
$route['product/(.*)/(.*)']='product/index/$1/$2';
```